# Chai Mocha testing works locally but does not work on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mocha.js, chai

I get the following error

```
Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Looking forward to hear from you guys, and thanks in advance!

Here is my code! Below is my test case that I am executing on Jenkins

```
describe('/candidateID route', () => {
  it('gets the candidate info', function (done) {
    chai.request(server)
      .get('/candidateInfo/' + candidateId + '/' + reqNum)
      .set('jwt', vcapServices.JWT_TOKEN)
      .end(function (err, res) {
        if(err) {
          done(err);
          return;
        }
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a('array');
        res.body.length.should.be.eql(1);
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('applicantId');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('requistionNumber');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('firstName');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('lastName');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('emailAddress');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('storeNumber');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('locationCountry');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('locationStateCode');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('firstAddress');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('secondAddress');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('thirdAddress');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('cityName');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('state');
        expect(res.body[0]).to.have.a.property('zipCode');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post an extract of your code that is not working to make it easier for members to possibly reproduce your issue and help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem with CircleCI. I updated the mocha.opts file with timeout parameter to resolve the issue. Not the most elegant solution but works.

```js
--timeout 99999999
```

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you can try defining timeout for the test at the 'describe' or 'it' level and see if it helps by using  this.timeout(10000);. The 'it' level timeout setting should override any other settings that may be getting enforced by Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Shmit! I tried using this.timeout(10000), but it did not work for me as well

Comment: I would really be interested in knowing the solution. Please do post it when you find it.

Comment: I would definitely do that @Shmit